# unknown type name ‘sockaddr’

Tags: c, linux, sockets

When I run

`cc    -c -o rawudp.o rawudp.c`

I get

In file included from rawudp.c:1:0: 
rawudp.h:48:23: error: unknown type name ‘sockaddr' 
make: *** [rawudp.o] Error 1

Here is the Header file that I use.

#### rawudp.h

```
#ifndef RAWUDP_H_
#define RAWUDP_H_ value

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>

// The packet length
#define PCKT_LEN 8192

//IP Header Constants
#define IP_HEADER_IHL       5;
#define IP_HEADER_VERSION   4;
#define IP_HEADER_TOS       16;
#define IP_HEADER_TTL       64;
#define IP_HEADER_PROTOCOL  17;

typedef struct ipheader {
 unsigned char      iph_ihl:5, iph_ver:4;
 unsigned char      iph_tos;
 unsigned short int iph_len;
 unsigned short int iph_ident;
 unsigned char      iph_flag;
 unsigned short int iph_offset;
 unsigned char      iph_ttl;
 unsigned char      iph_protocol;
 unsigned short int iph_chksum;
 unsigned int       iph_sourceip;
 unsigned int       iph_destip;
} ipheader;

// UDP header's structure
typedef struct udpheader {
 unsigned short int udph_srcport;
 unsigned short int udph_destport;
 unsigned short int udph_len;
 unsigned short int udph_chksum;
} udpheader;
#endif
```

#### rawudp.c

```
#include "rawudp.h"

// Function for checksum calculation. From the RFC,
// the checksum algorithm is:
//  "The checksum field is the 16 bit one's complement of the one's
//  complement sum of all 16 bit words in the header.  For purposes of
//  computing the checksum, the value of the checksum field is zero."
unsigned short csum(unsigned short *buf, int nwords)
{       //
        unsigned long sum;
        for(sum=0; nwords>0; nwords--)
                sum += *buf++;
        sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum &0xffff);
        sum += (sum >> 16);
        return (unsigned short)(~sum);
}

// Create a raw socket with UDP protocol
int udp_socket_init(){
        int socket_descriptor;
        socket_descriptor = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
        if(socket_descriptor < 0)
        {
                perror("socket() error");
                // If something wrong just exit
                exit(-1);
        }
        else
                return socket_descriptor;
                //printf("socket() - Using SOCK_RAW socket and UDP protocol is OK.\n");
}

int ip_socket_init(sockaddr_in* udp_socket, char* port, char* ip_address){
        udp_socket->sin_family = AF_INET;
        //Convert and set port number
        if (!(udp_socket->sin_port = htons(atoi(port)))){
                printf("Could not set port number\n");
                exit(-1);
        }
        //Convert and set IP Address
        if (!(udp_socket->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address)))
        {
                printf("Could not set IP address\n");
                exit(-1);
        }
        return 1;
}

int ip_header_init(ipheader* ip, char* source_ip, char* dest_ip, size_t size){
        // Fabricate the IP header or we can use the
        // standard header structures but assign our own values.
        ip->iph_ihl = IP_HEADER_IHL;
        ip->iph_ver = IP_HEADER_VERSION;
        ip->iph_tos = IP_HEADER_TOS; // Low delay
        ip->iph_len = size;
        ip->iph_ident = htons(54321);
        ip->iph_ttl = IP_HEADER_TTL; // hops
        ip->iph_protocol = IP_HEADER_PROTOCOL; // UDP
        // Source IP address, can use spoofed address here!!!
        ip->iph_sourceip = inet_addr(source_ip);
        // The destination IP address
        ip->iph_destip = inet_addr(dest_ip);
}

int udp_header_init(udpheader* udp, char* source_port, char* dest_port){
        // Fabricate the UDP header. Source port number, redundant
        udp->udph_srcport = htons(atoi(source_port));
        // Destination port number
        udp->udph_destport = htons(atoi(dest_port));
        udp->udph_len = htons(sizeof(struct udpheader));
}

// Source IP, source port, target IP, target port from the command line arguments
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int socket_descriptor;
        // No data/payload just datagram
        char buffer[PCKT_LEN];

        // Our own headers' structures
        struct ipheader *ip = (struct ipheader *) buffer;
        struct udpheader *udp = (struct udpheader *) (buffer + sizeof(struct ipheader));

        // Source and destination addresses: IP and port
        struct sockaddr_in sin;
        struct sockaddr_in din;

        socket_descriptor = udp_socket_init();


        int one = 1;
        const int *val = &one;

        bzero(buffer, PCKT_LEN);

        if(argc != 5)
        {
                printf("- Invalid parameters!!!\n");
                printf("- Usage %s <source hostname/IP> <source port> <target hostname/IP> <target port>\n", argv[0]);
                exit(-1);
        }

        ip_socket_init(&sin, argv[2], argv[1]);
        ip_socket_init(&din, argv[4], argv[3]);

        ip_header_init(ip, argv[1],  argv[3], sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct udpheader));

        udp_header_init(udp, argv[2], argv[4]);

        // Calculate the checksum for integrity
        ip->iph_chksum = csum((unsigned short *)buffer, sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct udpheader));
        // Inform the kernel do not fill up the packet structure. we will build our own...
        if(setsockopt(socket_descriptor, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one)) < 0)
        {
                perror("setsockopt() error");
                exit(-1);
        }
        else
                printf("setsockopt() is OK.\n");

        // Send loop, send for every 2 second for 100 count
        printf("Trying...\n");
        printf("Using raw socket and UDP protocol\n");
        printf("Using Source IP: %s port: %u, Target IP: %s port: %u.\n", argv[1], atoi(argv[2]), argv[3], atoi(argv[4]));

        int count;
        for(count = 1; count <=20; count++)
        {
                if(sendto(socket_descriptor, buffer, ip->iph_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0)
                // Verify
                {
                        perror("sendto() error");
                        exit(-1);
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("Count #%u - sendto() is OK.\n", count);
                        sleep(2);
                }
        }
        close(socket_descriptor);
        return 0;
}
```

I believe I have included the right headers but am unable to find the reason that sockaddr is not inclded in the header files. I have also tried sockaddr_in and still no dice.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I see no reference to `sockaddr` in the piece of code you show here...

Comment: I added the rawudp.c but it should be an import error in rawudp.h

Comment: What platform and compiler?  Tell me this isn't solaris... :\

Comment: It's `struct sockaddr`

Comment: @Kevin he's casting a pointer -- this is the right way to do it, but some places don't actually use a named struct, they just typedef an anonymous one.

Comment: @xaxxon As per my comment on your answer, I did check the source and it is `struct sockaddr`, not a typedef.

Comment: @GeneralZero there's something you've omitted that's causing the problem. I got a similar error on line 33, fixed by changing `sockaddr_in` to `struct sockaddr_in`, but `sockaddr` doesn't appear in your .h file as you've posted it.

Comment: Also, not directly related but undefined behavior: `control reaches end of non-void function`, i.e. missing `return`, for `ip_header_init` and `udp_header_init`

Comment: Could you try to specify `-I` in your compile command?

Comment: @xaxxon nope its Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @mattn 
cc -I -c -o rawudp.o rawudp.c
In file included from rawudp.c:1:0:
rawudp.h:48:23: error: unknown type name âsockaddrâ
rawudp.c:33:20: error: unknown type name âsockaddr_inâ

Comment: @Kevin I was trying both of them because I forgot which I needed but both had errors which didn't help me

Comment: @mattn if it weren't finding the header it would give that error instead of an unknown type name.

Comment: @GeneralZero Ah, sorry. Try `-I.` again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for all of the help guys its as you said.

### "sockaddr_in" is not a typedef

When using it you need to specify as such (also in function declarations)

```
struct sockaddr_in foo;

int bar(struct sockaddr_in);
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not a special case in this case, and every example code should have it right...

Comment: Just to clarify to anyone reading this - the point of this solution is that you need to prefix sockaddr_in with the struct keyword anytime you use it in a declaration.